# Can you use "neither" instead of "nor" in this case?

Tags: neither-nor

Is the usage of **"neither"** instead of **"nor"** grammatical in these sentences? :

> I did not believe his story, but **nor** did I believe hers.

> He didn't deny the reports, but **nor** did he confirm them.

Because I found these two sentences in pages with the definition of **"neither"**:

> I did not believe his story, but **neither** did I believe hers.

[The link to this sentence (conjunction, definition 2 for "neither")](https://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/neither)

> He didn't deny the reports, but **neither** did he confirm them.

[The link to this (the last sentence in the "More examples" section](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/neither)

Or just the usage of **"nor"** is actually correct here?
Please help!

*Thank you in advance!*

Comment: I'd expect the *but* out:  *I did not believe his story, [but] nor did I believe hers.* *He didn't deny the reports, [but] nor did he confirm them*.

Comment: Ok, but can you use "neither" instead of "nor" like in the links?

Comment: Yes, either neither or nor.

Comment: And are "neither" and "nor"  used just as often in this case? Or is there a difference between American English and British English in terms of how often they are used?

Comment: Or is there a difference in terms of how formal are the two?

Comment: _But neither_ is the normal use; _but nor_ strikes me as novel, though I don't really know.

Comment: No, sir, it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd agree with @JohnLawler's comment

> *But neither* is the normal use; *but nor* strikes me as novel, though I don't really know.

This is supported by a query to the [Google ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=but+neither%2C+but+nor&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbut%20neither%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbut%20nor%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cbut%20neither%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbut%20nor%3B%2Cc0), which shows that "but neither" is much more common than "but nor" (although the latter seems to be increasing recently):

[image]

As another point of comparison, here are some counts from the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) (COCA):

- - `NEITHER`: 74071, `. NEITHER`: 13370, `, NEITHER`: 9902, `BUT NEITHER` 3732, `; NEITHER`: 716
  - `NOR`: 88449, `, NOR`: 27236, `. NOR`: 11475, `; NOR`: 1935, `BUT NOR`: 118
- This supports the idea that "but neither" is somewhat rare but "but nor" is much rarer.
- it supports the idea that `, neither` is common.
- It also speaks to [your other question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/583564/is-nor-used-correctly-here-as-a-conjunction-nor-at-the-beginning-of-a-sent) about whether "nor" can be used at the beginning of a sentence. COCA indicates it often is.

Comment: Many people say that "but nor" is not grammatical because "nor" is already a coordinating conjunction that means "but neither" or "and neither" and therefore "but" shouldn't be here.

Comment: modern linguistics is generally *descriptive*; that is, you see what educated/native speakers actually do, then you figure out what implicit rules they're using. "Because it doesn't make sense" is not a very reliable way to reason about language ...

Comment: And also "[comma] neither" usage is considered by many as wrong because "neither" is an adverb, not a conjunction.

Comment: Do you come across the phrase "but nor" and "[comma] neither" often enough to think that the grammatical rules are nonsense?

Comment: I don't think grammatical rules are nonsense.  I think that trying to derive them by reasoning forward from "what is logical" is not necessarily going to work.

Comment: So, it means that I should listen to what the stats are showing. Thanks, for your help!