# Is "nor" used correctly here as a conjunction? ("nor" at the beginning of a sentence)

Tags: word-usage, conjunctions, periods

I came across this sentence when I searched for the definition of the word **"nor"**:

> *"Cooking quickly doesn't mean sacrificing flavour. **Nor** does fast food have to be junk food."*

[This is the source of the sentence (the 3rd definition of **"nor"**)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/nor)

On the site, **"nor"** is described as a *conjunction*, and my opinion is that it should have been like this:

> *Cooking quickly doesn't mean sacrificing flavour, **nor** does fast food have to be junk food.*

So, does the site show the right thing?

*Thank you in advance!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usage is fine. It would be similar to a phrase like "I went to technical school for three years. And I hated it" (or a similar construction with "but" instead of "and").

A [google search on "nor at the beginning of a sentence"](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fsq=%22nor%22+at+the+beginning+of+a+sentence) produces lots of hits, all agreeing that this is OK (but pointed out that it *used* to be discouraged by style guides).

[This site discusses sentences that begin with conjunctions](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/can-i-start-a-sentence-with-a-conjunction) more generally; specifically with [*coordinating conjunctions*](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/coordinating-conjunctions/) ("for", "and", "nor", "but", "or",  "yet", "so", ...).

[This site](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/when-use-nor) (the first one I happened to look at) says:

> 'Nor' without 'neither'

> “Nor” doesn’t necessarily have to appear in a sentence with the word “neither.” “Nor” can start a sentence. For example, if you’ve just mentioned that you don’t usually wake up at 6 a.m. and you want to continue being negative, you can start another sentence with “nor”: 'Nor do I like to wake up at 5 a.m.'

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! Now I'm sure that I can use "nor" and any other coordinating conjunction like in the quote.