# Can "neither" be a conjunction by itself?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, conjunctions

On [LDOCE](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/neither), at the definition page of **"neither"**, there is one definition that describes the word as a *conjunction*, with the sentence:

> *The authorities were not sympathetic to the students’ demands, **neither** would they tolerate any disruption.*

Is the usage of the word after a comma as a *conjunction* by itself as in the sentence really grammatical? If so, how often is **"neither"** used like this? Is this usage of **"neither**" as common in *American English* as it is in *British English*?

*Thank you in advance!*

Comment: Can you define "used like this" more precisely?

Comment: *"used like this"* means *"used after a comma as a conjunction by itself"* as in the sentence.

Comment: Notice that you can't insert and / but / yet / so ... for neither. 'Nor' and 'neither' trigger inversion, as do 'seldom' and 'rarely'. The FANBOYS approximation is too imperfect to be retained, and CGEL and ACGEL have alternative analyses.

Comment: This kind of gets off topic, but, I thought that **"and", "but"** ... can be used before **"neither"** (and also before **"nor"** just in UK) in this type of sentence (*... were not sympathetic, ... **and/but neither** would they tolerate ...*)

Comment: "and" and "but" can be used *before* "neither", I believe (not precisely sure which usages @EdwinAshworth is referring to). "not ..., but neither" or "not ..., and neither" both seem fine to me ("not ..., nor", "not ..., and nor" and "not ..., but nor" seem wrong or at least very unusual)

Comment: @Ben Bolker You said that you find *"... were not sympathetic ..., **nor** would they tolerate ..."* wrong or unusual?

Comment: sorry. ", nor" sounds right. ", but nor" and ", and nor" sound unusual. ("but nor" is maybe a little worse than "and nor" ...)

Comment: @Ben Bolker Notice that you can't insert and / but / yet / so ... for neither. eg << *The authorities were not sympathetic to the students’ demands, _**and**_ would they tolerate any disruption. >> // << The authorities were not sympathetic to the students’ demands ... and would they tolerate any disruption? >> changes the sentence structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, it is grammatical; do you have a particular reason to doubt the reliability of the source you quoted (Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English)?
2. Doesn't my answer to your [previous question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/583443/can-you-use-neither-instead-of-nor-in-this-case) also cover this case? Specifically, in the [Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA)](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/), "neither" occurs 74071 times, while "neither" following a comma occurs 9902 times, so the frequency is 13% of the usage of "neither". Seems pretty common to me.

   I used "used following a comma" as a way to operationalize your statement "used like this"; if you  have a more specific class of usage in mind, you should say so [although a more limited set of grammatical cases might be beyond my capabilities in corpus analysis].

   I don't have a handy corpus of British English, so I can't do the British/American usage comparison. In my personal experience (lived 3 years in England, 11 in Canada, more than that in the US) this doesn't stand out to me as an unusual usage in any of those places — although it does seem a little bit formal/old-fashioned.

Comment: I agree.  The usage is fine, if slightly formal or elevated in tone.  You could also replace "neither" with "nor."  Using the absolute best wording and writing for the old New York times, I would say: "The authorities were neither sympathetic to the students' demands nor tolerant of any disruption.

Comment: I'm not sure that "used following a comma" operationalizes OP's "used like this". For example: "On Monday, neither Bob nor Mary showed up to work." "Neither" follows a comma but is not "a conjunction by itself" (as OP means).

Comment: @MarcInManhattan, I agree. I can use wild cards to represent a word and can insert parts of speech, but I'm not sure how to properly restrict the search to the usage that OP is looking for. (I don't think I can search for "not [1 or more words], neither"; "not * *, neither brings up for example "While the girls' troubles are not downplayed , neither are their courage"

Comment: @BenBolker Yeah, I don't know how to do that either, unfortunately.

Comment: '...  a particular reason to doubt the reliability of the source ... quoted (Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English)'. Here are two: Quirk et al class this usage of **neither** as an **additive subjunct** and Huddleston & Pullum classify it as an  **adverb operating as a connective adjunct**.

Comment: Quirk, Huddleston & Pullum are a little over my head. My guess would be that LDoCE is being less precise than a real grammarian would be ("specifically designed for learners and teachers of English, and for people who need to use English as a second language at work"; not necessarily users who would appreciate the difference between a conjunction and additive subjunct ...)  Feel free to post an alternative answer ...

Comment: ELU is aimed at linguists and serious (not basic-level) students of the language. Dictionaries, when they give different POSs from respected grammars, are reckoned to be incorrect.

Comment: That's fine. I think you're operating at a different level from the OP, but I would be happy to see a more technical answer.

Comment: My actual intention is to know whether **"neither"** can be used after a comma by itself as in the sentence rather than knowing whether it's a *conjunction* or an *additive subjunct* or an *adverb operating as a connective adjunct*. And also I'd like to know how often it's used in general and in America compared with UK.

Comment: @AlexFrt, I think this is the best I can do for now.